# Nil returned from a method that is expected to return a non-null value

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm implementing `UIKeyInput`, `UITextInputTraits`, and `UITextInput` and with that I'm required to implement:

```
- (NSArray *)selectionRectsForRange:(UITextRange *)range
{
    return nil;
}
```

However, in analyzing my project I get: "nil returned from a method that is expected to return a non-null value".

What would be the correct way to get rid of this? Should I do an abort?

Comment: "Should I just terminate the program"? What does that mean? Pull the plug on your computer?

Comment: @matt I changed it, I meant to say, should I do an abort().

Comment: @SerPounce pls check my answer. ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return `nil`. If you have no 
UITextSelectionRects to return, return an empty array.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way than just initializing an NSArray to a length of 1 and returning it?

Comment: Not a length of 1. Empty.

Comment: Never mind I just did: return [[NSArray alloc] init];

Comment: `return @[];` perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

Actually if you look at the header source, the method has `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` tag attached to it. So in short the `selectionRectsForRange` becomes a non null return method.

```
//
//  UITextInput.h
//  UIKit
//
//  Copyright (c) 2009-2017 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <UIKit/UITextInputTraits.h>
#import <UIKit/UIResponder.h>

...

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN  // <--- HERE!
..
- (CGRect)firstRectForRange:(UITextRange *)range;
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position;
- (NSArray *)selectionRectsForRange:(UITextRange *)range NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

So you cannot return null or nil. Instead return an empty array like so:

```
- (NSArray *)selectionRectsForRange:(UITextRange *)range
{
    return @[];
}
```