# Are Objective-C function results nonnull by default?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, non-nullable, objective-c-nullability

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928348/nil-returned-from-a-method-that-is-expected-to-return-a-non-null-value#45928348) on implementing a `UITextInput` delegate method, the poster says that when they run static analysis on their code, they get an error on this function:

```
- (NSArray *)selectionRectsForRange:(UITextRange *)range
{
    return nil;
}
```

The error is "nil returned from a method that is expected to return a non-null value."

The function declaration does not have a nullability specifier on the result. Are function results non-null by default? (I work mostly in Swift these days, and am not expert on the latest changes to Objective-C.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not.

The header where that method is declared is bracketed with [the "assume nonnull" macros](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID45):

```
//
//  UITextInput.h
//  UIKit
//
//  Copyright (c) 2009-2017 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

#import <UIKit/UITextInputTraits.h>
#import <UIKit/UIResponder.h>

//===================================================================================================
// Responders that implement the UIKeyInput protocol will be driven by the system-provided keyboard,
// which will be made available whenever a conforming responder becomes first responder.

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

// snip
// ...
// L150
/* Geometry used to provide, for example, a correction rect. */
- (CGRect)firstRectForRange:(UITextRange *)range;
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position;
- (NSArray *)selectionRectsForRange:(UITextRange *)range NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);       // Returns an array of UITextSelectionRects
```

---

So this method has in fact been marked as having a non-null return value.

Comment: Being pedantic but the method is not explicitly marked as having a non-null return value. That would require the use of `- (NSArray * _Nonnull)selection...`. The use of `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` *implicitly* marks all of the methods until the `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END`.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. (And rmaddy, the whole block of methods has ben marked as returning non-null values.) Seems like the docs  on those methods should list them as nonnull however.